# How to import a variable from different file types

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain a variable from a different file type and import it into a Python script. The file is version.mk, it has a variable called VARIABLE_ID. The import module does not work as normally, is there any way to call variables from other file types?

Thanks for any help

```
import os

from version import VERSION_ID

def versionid:

    print VERSION_ID
```

This is the code that does not work.

The version ID is 0.0.2 format. When I run the below code it says there is a syntax error in the number.

I have read that distutils has a version numbering convention. I am not sure how this could be used, has anyone heard or know how this works?

Is there a way of having cooments in this file, when comments are in the file it interferes with the file. Could the read() just read the version_id and not the comments, thanks

```
VERSION_ID=map(int,re.match("VERSION_ID\s*=\s*(\S+)",open("version.mk").read()).group(1).split("."))
```

Comment: Are you trying to "read" a makefile?  Why are you saying the word "import" when you're not talking about Python, but talking about a makefile?

Comment: Hi, could you post version.mk or part of it?

Comment: I have updated answer, should use re.search, instead of re.match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure about `version.mk` is valid python file, and does not have any harm codes, you can execute it.

```
>>> exec(open("version.mk"))
>>> print VERSION_ID
1
```

---

**UPDATE**: because OP Added VERSION_ID is not a valid python number

**version.mk**

```
#version no is here
VERSION_ID=0.0.2

#some more info here
....
```

-

```
>>> import re
>>> VERSION_ID=map(int,re.search("VERSION_ID\s*=\s*(\S+)",open("version.mk").read()).group(1).split("."))
>>> VERSION_ID
[0, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file isn't Python code, you can't import it as if it were.

You need to open the file manually and parse for the setting. Especially if the line containing the number is something like

```
VERSION_ID = 0.0.2
```

Since this can never be valid Python (there's no literal that looks like that).

This might be a case where a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) makes sense, something like `r'VERSION_ID\s*=\s*([0-9.]+)` could work.